# c# sha256 compute password hash by using username as salt

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, hash, sha256

I am trying to compute password hash with `username` as a salt. I have stored password_hash and password_salt in MySQL database.

```
-- Generate salt
SET @salt = UNHEX(SHA2(UUID(), 256));

-- Create user and hash password with salt
INSERT INTO users (username, password_salt, password_hash)
  VALUES ('ajay', @salt, UNHEX(SHA2(CONCAT('ajay123', HEX(@salt)), 256)));
```

By using above method I insert the value in database. Now I am trying to login to my site by `username` and `password` but I have a problem in authenticating to user. I am trying to compute hash of password in c# but I am getting wrong one. I have tried following code.

```
 byte[] ComputedHashpass = ComputeHash("ajay", "ajay123");            
 var result = ComputedHashpass.SequenceEqual(passHash);

  public static byte[] ComputeHash(string salt,string password)
   {
       // Convert plain text into a byte array.
       byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
       byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);

       SHA256Managed hash = new SHA256Managed();

       // Compute hash value of salt.
       byte[] plainHash = hash.ComputeHash(plainTextBytes);

       byte[] concat = new byte[plainHash.Length + saltBytes.Length];

       System.Buffer.BlockCopy(saltBytes, 0, concat, 0, saltBytes.Length);
       System.Buffer.BlockCopy(plainHash, 0, concat, saltBytes.Length, plainHash.Length);

       byte[] tHashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(concat);

       // Convert result into a base64-encoded string.
       //string hashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(tHashBytes);

       // Return the result.
       //return hashValue;
       return tHashBytes;
   }
```

**UPDATED METHOD**

```
   public static byte[] ComputeHash(string salt,string password)
   {
       // Convert plain text into a byte array.
       byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
       byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);

       SHA256Managed hash = new SHA256Managed();

       // Compute hash value of salt.
       //byte[] plainHash = hash.ComputeHash(plainTextBytes);

       // Compute hash value of salt.
       byte[] saltHash = hash.ComputeHash(saltBytes);
       byte[] concat = new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + saltHash.Length];
       System.Buffer.BlockCopy(plainTextBytes, 0, concat, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
       System.Buffer.BlockCopy(saltHash, 0, concat, plainTextBytes.Length, saltHash.Length);


       //byte[] concat = new byte[plainHash.Length + saltBytes.Length];

       //System.Buffer.BlockCopy(saltBytes, 0, concat, 0, saltBytes.Length);
       //System.Buffer.BlockCopy(plainHash, 0, concat, saltBytes.Length, plainHash.Length);

       byte[] tHashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(concat);

       // Convert result into a base64-encoded string.
       //string hashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(tHashBytes);

       // Return the result.
       //return hashValue;
       return tHashBytes;
   }
```

Here I used salt as `username`. Can some one help me to solve this. How can I compute the hash password?

I want to do following steps.

To check whether a username/password combination is valid:

```
1: Query the salt using the entered username
2: Apply the hash function to the password and salt
3: Compare the result against the stored hash
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2**

(Removed the previous text to not to confuse).

The updated code you wrote is not what I proposed.
This is something more like what I propsed:

```
-- Generate salt
SET @salt = UNHEX(SHA2(UUID(), 256));

-- Create user and hash password with salt
INSERT INTO users (username, password_salt, password_hash)
  VALUES ('ajay', @salt, UNHEX(SHA2(CONCAT('ajay123', @salt), 256)));
```

---

```
public static byte[] ComputeHash(string salt,string password)
{
  byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
  byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);

  byte[] concat = new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + saltBytes .Length];
  System.Buffer.BlockCopy(plainTextBytes, 0, concat, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
  System.Buffer.BlockCopy(saltBytes , 0, concat, plainTextBytes.Length, saltBytes .Length);

  SHA256Managed hash = new SHA256Managed();

  byte[] tHashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(concat);

  return tHashBytes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. I have edited my questions. Please check it. I have changed this `SET @salt = UNHEX(SHA2(UUID(), 256));` to this `SET @salt = UNHEX(SHA2('ajay', 256));` and change the code according to you but still not matches

Comment: I have added new user by using this `-- Generate salt
SET @salt = UNHEX(SHA2('demo', 256));

-- Create user and hash password with salt
INSERT INTO guacamole_user (username, password_salt, password_hash)
     VALUES ('demo', @salt, UNHEX(SHA2(CONCAT('demo123', HEX(@salt)), 256)));`

Comment: Please check this. I have asked question. https://sourceforge.net/p/guacamole/discussion/1110834/thread/f276a909/?limit=25#dbf3

Comment: Please check I have updated my method according to yours. But still not solved.

Comment: Does anyone as come right with the following above? I'm so struggling to get the correct SALT value replication!